# ObjectPool not reusing objects as expected. How can I design this to pool resources?

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused on how to return an object(successfully) back to a pool.  I am testing creating a pool of channels for rabbitmq(this doesn't have anything to do specifically with rabbitmq though).  The process in rabbitmq is to create a connection to a server, then create a channel and I'm trying to have it create channels and use part of a pool but it just keeps creating new ones and does not seem to reuse older channels.  I believe this is so because when I check the web UI for rabbit it says I have as many channels as I have items in my queue but my upload speed is about 10k messages a second so I would expect to only have channels around that range.

I am pretty sure this is happening because I have no process(or idea) how to successfully return to the pool. I am using returnObject but do I need to do anything to make it ready to use by another process?

Here's the code(its alot of code but I think the problem is in the `MyPooledObject class` and in the  `pool.returnObject(obj)` part:

```
import org.apache.commons.pool.BasePoolableObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool;
import org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.MessageProperties;

public class PoolExample {
    public static class MyPooledObject {
        Connection connection;
        public MyPooledObject() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("hello world");
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("localhost");
            connection = factory.newConnection();

        }

        public Channel sing() throws IOException {
            //System.out.println("mary had a little lamb");
            return connection.createChannel();
        }

        public void destroy() {
            System.out.println("goodbye cruel world");

        }
    }

    public static class MyPoolableObjectFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<MyPooledObject> {
        @Override
        public MyPooledObject makeObject() throws Exception {
            return new MyPooledObject();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyObject(MyPooledObject obj) throws Exception {
            obj.destroy();
        }
        // PoolableObjectFactory has other methods you can override
        // to valdiate, activate, and passivate objects.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PoolableObjectFactory<MyPooledObject> factory = new MyPoolableObjectFactory();
        ObjectPool<MyPooledObject> pool = new GenericObjectPool<MyPooledObject>(factory);

        // Other ObjectPool implementations with special behaviors are available;
        // see the JavaDoc for details

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) {
                MyPooledObject obj;

                try {
                    obj = pool.borrowObject();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // failed to borrow object; you get to decide how to handle this
                    throw e;
                }

                try {
                    // use the pooled object
                    Channel channel = obj.sing();
                    String message = "Mary Had a little lamb";
                    channel.basicPublish( "", "task_queue", 
                            MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN,
                            message.getBytes());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // this object has failed us -- never use it again!
                    pool.invalidateObject(obj);
                    obj = null; // don't return it to the pool

                    // now handle the exception however you want

                } finally {
                    if (obj != null) {
                        pool.returnObject(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            pool.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is as expected.  Put a break point on makeObject, you'll find that you only ever use it once, because you only use one object in the pool at a time.

If you were to use multiple objects in the pool at the same time, the pool would fill up and be using different objects.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused.  I thought I only needed to makeObject once as it creates the initial connection and then use the other method to spawn channels based on it.

Comment: If I'm only using one object at one time then shouldn't at max I only have one channel.  In this case, I have as many channels as I am uploading data and it keeps increasing. I think your right but I don't understand how to fix it to get the behavior I'm hoping for.

Comment: Every time you call sing, you create a channel, not reuse an existing channel.  If you want to reuse an existing channel, call createChannel in the constructor, and then just return it in the sing method.